# Symfony2 does not recognize APC

Tags: php, symfony, apc

Symfony2 does not seem eager to identify the APC extension, despite the latter is being available as "php -m" demonstrates:

[PHP Modules]
apc
apcu
bcmath
bz2
...
...

The logs show:
    *FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to use ApcClassLoader as APC is not enabled.'*

My PHP version is: 5.5.9.
Any guesses would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** phpinfo() somehow shows that APC is not enabled, however php -m includes it in.

Comment: Are you sure that, PHP configuration for CLI and Apache/HTTP server are identical? What does `phpinfo()` return?

Comment: We actually run on nginx. Where should I look into ?

Comment: Restart the web server to apply changes?

Comment: @iswinky That is already done.

Comment: `service php5-fpm restart` ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `phpinfo()` via your browser to see if it says it on there?

Comment: @Qoop see update on my first post ;)

Comment: You need to enable it for your browser version of `php`. The ini location will be in your `phpinfo` output.

Comment: It seems - like at the past- APC reinstallation fails:



make: *** [apc_compile.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue seems to be resolved.
My box contains two php.ini files, one located at /cli/php.ini and another one at /fpm/php.ini.

I needed to uninstall and reinstall the APC package several times to see it actually working.
Thanks all!